# Why isn't my responseText working in the if condition (works elsewhere)?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my Javascript in my html file. I'm making a simple login functionality using an API. The API post request returns either "login passed" or "login failed".

Window.alert(datas)in myFunction3(), which returns "login passed" is returning "login passed", however nothing in the if condition works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



  function myFunction2(){
    //grab user entered values for posting to API
    uid=document.getElementById('username').value;
    pass=document.getElementById('password').value;

    //Generate url for Post request
    var url='http://127.0.0.1:5000//login/'+uid+'/'+pass
    
   
   //making Post request to API
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
   xhr.open("POST", url);  
   xhr.send(); 

  
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(xhr.readyState==4&&xhr.status==200){
        if(xhr.responseText){
           const data = xhr.responseText; //json returned by post request
            myFunction3(data); 
           
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function myFunction3(datas){
        window.alert(datas);
         
        if(datas == "login passed"){
          
          localStorage.setItem("user",uid);
          console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"));
          window.alert(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        }
        
  }


</script>
```

Comment: Check for whitespaces, as your api might be accidently adding them causing the values to not equal, eg `"login passed" != "login passed "`

Comment: Use `console.log()` starting at the top of onreadystatechange function and inside each condition to track where the issue actually is. Right it has to pass 2 conditions before you get an alert.

Comment: Expanding upon @PatrickEvans comment, I'd say this is perhaps a good reason to avoid comparing arbitrary strings.  A better alternative might be to have the API return an object with a boolean, such as `{ isAuthenticated: true }`.

Comment: the api is returning "login passed" on postman

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that of scope:

```
function myFunction2(){
    //grab user entered values for posting to API
    uid=document.getElementById('username').value;
    pass=document.getElementById('password').value;

    //Generate url for Post request
    var url='http://127.0.0.1:5000//login/'+uid+'/'+pass
    
   
   //making Post request to API
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
   xhr.open("POST", url);  
   xhr.send(); 

  
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(xhr.readyState==4&&xhr.status==200){
        if(xhr.responseText){
           const data = xhr.responseText; //json returned by post request
            myFunction3(data); 
           
        }
      }
    }
 
    // this function needs to be in scope so uid is valid
    function myFunction3(datas){
        window.alert(datas);
         
        if(datas == "login passed"){
          
          localStorage.setItem("user",uid);
          console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"));
          window.alert(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        }
        
  }

  }
```

Try moving your function myFunction3 inside the myFunction2. Your if statement is working, the issue is uid will equal nothing since it does not exist in the global scope.

You can also fix the problem by declaring uid in the global scope outside of myFunction2, at the top of your code.

```
var uid="unauthorized";
```